# Use SNS to post through HTTPS using OAuth2 with bearer token

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm considering the use of SNS to send POST request to customer API from a Lambda function.
My difficulty is how to manage the fetch of the token and token refresh. The goal is to first do a request to get a token, using Basic authentication and then, with a valid token, do the POST request whenever I get a new message on the corresponding topic.
Additionally I'd like to understand if the token refresh process can be managed out of the box with SNS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth 2 is not supported via SNS - the only options is Basic and Digest auth: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html